# Weird line showed up on my donut

Tags: modeling

[image]

I was doing the donut tutorial and I got to using cycles engine and this weird line showed up on my icing. If I lower the subsurface down to 0, it become a blur instead of a line.

I think the line is the vertex edge, so I've tried scaling it, moving it, and deleting some of the extra vertices around it but sadly the line is still there.

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell. Looks like duplicate verts maybe? Select all in edit mode > M (merge) > By Distance.

Comment: I merged it but it said 0 vertices removed .  looking at the drip bit, it has extra vertices. The line is still there

Comment: Just a guess. Something like: at some point, you made an extrusion of the single-skin icing, and 'cancelled' it  with a right-click. This did  _not_ wipe out the extrusion (that would have to be Ctrl-Z), but left it in place, 0-length. After _Solidify_, you have an internal face / doubled verts. H hide some faces, jiggle some verts around, look for the error manually.

Comment: Deleted all the extra vertices and it fixed the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe you have an interior face around that area, cause it looks like it's also effecting the smoothing too.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide some faces you can see the interior of your mesh, as you see you have inner faces, it creates bad shading as Blender shades between outer and inner faces, remove them:

[image]